# How can I avoid repetition of "I", while keeping present tense in first person?

Tags: fiction, novel, tenses, grammatical-person

I'm writing a first-person fantasy novel. I can't exactly figure out how to avoid the repetition of "I" when explaining the actions of the character. *Any way I have ever seen makes the story seem like it's being entirely told in past-tense*, and I believe that would take away from how I want to portray things.

**This question is unique because it asks how to maintain the tense, unlike the possible duplicate.**

**The possible duplicate also doesn't provide an answer in which the present tense is maintained.**

Comment: The tense used has nothing to do with the point of view used.

Comment: @JasonBassford Okay, I'll further explain why its not a duplicate in my edit.

Comment: The top answer in the linked duplicate works perfectly well in present tense.  Change the tense of the example given and the result is exactly what you'd want.  Similarly for @StuW's answer - just change the tense and the given example works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the fact you're writing in present tense makes much of a difference, and if you do it'd be worth discussing why, for instance, the write-this-not-that examples in the other question wouldn't work as well in the present tense. My go-to present-tense author is Damon Runyon, and his first-person stories are also a good exercise in scant use of "I". [This](https://damonrunyon.neocities.org/Broadway_Stories/A_Piece_of_Pie.html), for example, has the narrator more of an onlooker who's not involved much. That might not suit your purposes, but his sentence structures could give you ideas.

[This](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/the-use-of-%E2%80%9Ci%E2%80%9D-in-first-person-narration/) survey found a 3% use of "I" by word count in one author's first-person writing. I don't use first-person often myself, but when I do the total is more like 4%. You should ask yourself whether you *are* overusing it. The frequency of "I" can attest to the character's extent of self-absorption, which for my protagonist was a definite character trait. You might, *might*, find writing a self-obsessed character works more to your strengths than worrying about your overuse.

Comment: My character is self-absorbed. You could definitely say that. I personally find that having to have an "I" at the beginning of a sentence where he does some kind of action is going to grow to be tedious. I try to deeply portray what the character is experiencing, and observing in order to keep the "I"s from annoying the reader. Because the character is alone now and for a little while, I only have action, experience, observation, and thought to work with until more characters are introduced to the story. I might have to introduce another character quicker than I wanted.

Comment: @KeithCronin Ah, the overuse of "I" *at the start of a sentence* is a different issue; but you'll get around that with practice. The problem may be not so much your overuse of "I" as your sentences having similar structures.

Answer (score 0):

Sir, there is a way by which you can minimize the use of I in the first place. As you are writing a first-person fantasy you can always use other characters to tell your story in this manner you can always skip the letter I.

Let the sub-character tell first-person's story, so the story will keep everyone engaged.

it's a fantasy after all you can make the nonliving things tell your story also.

Comment: I agree with that, but, the character that I'm in first person with right now is completely alone, and will be until the next main character is introduced.